# Replace bullets with dashes in a Word document

Tags: delphi, vba, ms-word, activex

I'm trying to replace the bullets of a list in a word document with dashes, basically only the "rendered icon" to be replaced, i.e.

**Replace bullets from the below list:**

- this is a list item
- this is another list item
- yet another item

**with dashes:**

> — this is a list item
>
> — this is another list item
>
> — yet another item

I'm going to do this using ActiveX in Delphi, but VB code would also do, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within **Delphi** code:

```
uses ..., ComObj;

const
  wdListNumberStyleBullet = 23;
var
  vMSWord                      : variant;
    Doc                          : Variant;
  oListTemplate                : Variant;
  oListLevel                   : Variant;
  iLoopTemplates, iMaxTemplates: Integer;
  iLoopLevels, iMaxLevels      : Integer;
begin
  try
    vMSWord         := GetActiveOleObject('Word.Application');
    vMSWord.Visible := True;
    Doc             := vMSWord.ActiveDocument;
    iMaxTemplates   := Doc.ListTemplates.Count;
    for iLoopTemplates := 1 to iMaxTemplates do
    begin
      oListTemplate := Doc.ListTemplates.Item(iLoopTemplates);
      iMaxLevels    := oListTemplate.ListLevels.Count;
      for iLoopLevels := 1 to iMaxLevels do
      begin
        oListLevel := oListTemplate.ListLevels.Item(iLoopLevels);
        if      (oListLevel.NumberStyle  = wdListNumberStyleBullet)
            and (oListLevel.NumberFormat = UTF8String(#61623))
            and (oListLevel.Font.Name    = 'Symbol') then
//        if (oListLevel.NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleBullet) then
        begin
          oListLevel.NumberFormat := UTF8String('-');
          oListLevel.Font.Name    := 'Arial';
        end;
      end;
    end;
  except
    ShowMessage('Open a Word document before running this method');
  end;
```

The current ***IF*** is checking if it's really a •bullet wih a •

If you don't need this check, comment this line (*if...*) and uncomment the next one...

Comment: +1 thank you very much, still didn't look into this, but if your code works out of the box, I'll accept this as answer! (:

Comment: I've tested it with Delphi XE2 & Word 2010... so, this should work for you too... ;o)

Comment: thank you for the extra effort to provide delphi code, I've accepted your answer because of the extra effort.

Comment: well, a few slight changes, but nothing earth shattering (:

Comment: FYI, I tested it with Delphi XE2 & Word 2010... ;o)

Comment: no worries, forgot to mention, I'm using this in Delphi 5 ((:

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

'~~> Select the relevant range before running this code
Sub Sample()
    With ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
        .NumberFormat = ChrW(61485)
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleBullet
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .ResetOnHigher = 0
        .StartAt = 1
        .Font.Name = "Symbol"
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1).Name = ""

    Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
    ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
    False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToSelection, DefaultListBehavior:= _
    wdWord10ListBehavior
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A macro which does the job...

```
Dim oListTemplate As ListTemplate
Dim oListLevel As ListLevel

For Each oListTemplate In ActiveDocument.ListTemplates
    For Each oListLevel In oListTemplate.ListLevels
        If oListLevel.NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleBullet Then
            With oListLevel
                .NumberFormat = "-"
                .Font.Name = "Arial"
            End With
        End If
    Next oListLevel
Next oListTemplate
```

Comment: I think this a much better and much more robust solution. The former looks like it's just the result of recording a macro, and won't work on multiple lists or machines with a different set of list templates.

Comment: @DorinDuminica: I don't know if you need to *only* replace the *bullets* with dashes... if yes, you need to add a second test to check if the current character is: .NumberFormat = ChrW(61623) AND .Font.Name = "Symbol"